# In my React JS application, My onClick function is happening on Load, not when I click on the button. Trying to sort JSON array

Tags: reactjs

//These are the functions that I am using

```
  function payLeast(a,b) {
       return parseInt(a.pay, 10) - parseInt(b.pay, 10);
  }

  function sort(x){
       testData.sort(x)
  }
```

**this is the Application function**

```
class App extends Component{
   render(){
     return(
         <html>    
         <div className = "mainContainer">
         <div className = "formContainer">
          <form >
          <div className = "searchContainer" align = "left">
              <Dropdown title = "Click to see Searches" items = {items} multiSelect />
              <input type="submit" value="Submit"></input>
          </div>
          <div className = "criteriaContainer">
          <button type = "button" onClick={sort(payLeast)}>Pay</button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <button>dateAdded</button>
          </div>
          <div className = "JSONContainer" >
              <Query title = "Enter JSON Job Query Below"/>
          </div>
          <br></br>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
<button type = "button" onClick={sort(payLeast)}>Pay</button>
```

to

```
<button type = "button" onClick={() => sort(payLeast)}>Pay</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are calling `sort(payLeast)` during the render statement.

Instead, define an inline function like so.

```js
<button type = "button" onClick={() => sort(payLeast)}>Pay</button>
```

Comment: when I called that, now the function is not calling , the JSON query remains unsorted

Comment: It looks like you need to do something with the sorted result. Consider assigning it to a state variable.